# Display none in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like delete this code with Css.

How can I apply "display none" for the code:

```
<div class="option " data-id="2">SAQSQS</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The answer and info for this is published on many global css websites. I highly suggest taking a css basics course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute as a selector so:

```
.option[data-id="2"] {
  display: none;
}
```

See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

HTML:
`<div class="option" data-id="2">SAQSQS</div>`
(remove the space after option). In css, write

```
.option{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work. It should be somewhere id="2"